# Extract part between two strings in a variable in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a string,

```
tester_one="update set_tables set abc=7 where bcd=9"
```

Here I wish to extract only the part between "set" and "where",

```
abc=7
```

I tried a couple of Unix commands, but it picked up any occurrences of *set* or where encountered, before the part where I want it to pick up.

I have an idea on how to do it Java but I am lost in Unix as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it out with sed. Something like:

```
echo "$tester_one" | sed 's/.* set \(.*\) where .*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks @viraptor!! It works like a Charm!! Might be too much to ask....Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: The `(.*)` catches everything between, and it will be placed in variable \1 (default `sed` behavior). He then proceeds to substitute the entire input with the \1 variable.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @Liviu Chircu

Answer (score 5):

#### Using sed

```
$ echo "$tester_one" | sed -E 's/.*set (.*) where.*/\1/'
abc=7
```

To capture it in a variable:

```
$ new=$(echo "$tester_one" | sed -E 's/.*set (.*) where.*/\1/')
$ echo $new
abc=7
```

#### Using awk

```
$ echo "$tester_one" | awk '{sub(/.*set /,""); sub(/ where.*/,""); print;}'
abc=7
```

#### Using grep -P

If your grep supports the `-P` (perl-like) option:

```
$ echo "$tester_one" | grep -oP '(?<=set ).*(?= where)'
abc=7
```

Comment: Thanks @John1024. All of them work!! Just a doubt, are you matching the pattern b/w "set " and " where"?

Comment: @Noobie Yes, they all return text between `set ` and ` where`.

Comment: Would all these commands still work still work if i replace "set " with " set " as I am assuming for a query like "update abc_set set abc=7 where bcd=9", the line might get parsed wrongly

Comment: @Noobie That would be fine: all the commands would work if you add that space.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bash Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
#!/bin/bash
tester_one="update set_tables set abc=7 where bcd=9"
pat=".* set (.*) where"
[[ $tester_one =~ $pat ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: I always forget that bash can do this. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `set` and `where` as field separators and print the field that lies in between them:

```
$ awk -F"set | where" '{print $2}' <<< "update set_tables set abc=7 where bcd=9"
abc=7
```

Answer (score 0):

As with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31673358/1072112), this can be achieved in pure bash, without the use of external tools like sed/awk/grep.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tester_one="update set_tables set abc=7 where bcd=9"

output="${tester_one#* set }"
output="${output% where }"

echo "$output"
```

Note the spaces around "set" and "where" in the parameter expansion lines.  As you might expect, you'll need to be careful with this if the `$tester_one` variable contains the distinct "set" or "where" in places that you don't expect them.

That said, I like [Jahid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671307/1072112) better. :-)